# Possible to save a table as a .png with reportlab? (Python)

Tags: python, png, reportlab

Using: Python 2.7.5 and reportlab

Goal: scrape data and create a table from it, then save it as a png/jpg to be uploaded elsewhere.

I am able to create the table using reportlab and was able to save it as a pdf, but couldn't find a way to save it as a png, is there a way to do this?  If it's not possible in reportlab, is there another Python package that has this capability?

Code for creating the table:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Table, SimpleDocTemplate

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('Test.pdf', pagesize=letter)

elements = []
data = [(1,2),(3,4)]
table = Table(data)

elements.append(table)
doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: Even if `reportlab` doesn't support PNG output at all (I don't know), there are several command line tools for PDF to image conversion that you could call from Python (e.g. `pdftocairo`) via a `subprocess` or libraries like `PythonMagick` that you can use too, example [here](http://p-s.co.nz/wordpress/pdf-to-png-using-pythonmagick/).

Comment: I looked some more and it definitely does support png, it has a save and renderPM function that both allow for png however I can't get the table into a format that can be passed to one of those functions, and the documentation for ReportLab is scarce.

I'll look at the ones you listed, but would really like it to use as few packages as possible.  Thanks for the help.